# VS Community: No HTML Highlight

Tags: html, visual-studio, razor, syntax-highlighting, intellisense

After working back with my project I saw that my HTML doesn't highlight and Razor Intellisense is not working at all. Any ideas how to fix it? Tried to reset settings and even reinstalling whole VS?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've installed `DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.2.exe` and then run `devenv.exe /resetuserdata`, later on I've deleted .vs folder inside my project folder. When I run my project again everything was working properly. The problem was I didn't even have Web Templates when I was trying to create new project, after installing above they have shown in New Project templates.